# How to assign user input to a variable or list

Tags: python, list, variables, input

Let's say that I have a line with: `a = input("Enter your name and age:")`
How can I make the variable "a" store each section of the input, lets say "George 25" as "George, 25" either as a standard variable or a list? All I want to do is be able to store user input as separate elements in a list or variable so that input with words separated by a space would become separate elements in a variable. Is this clear enough? I am using Python 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
user_input_list = input("Enter your name and age:").split(' ')
```

This creates a *list* of each space-separated word in the input.

```
>>> 'George 25'.split(' ')
['George', '25']
```

Then you can access each part as:

```
user_input_list[0] # George
user_input_list[1] # 25
```

Is that what you're after ?

Comment: Except it's a `list` not a `tuple`.